# How to remove Taskbar and Start Menu option from the start menu?

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu, control-panel, regedit

On XP's "classic start menu" under settings there is an item Taskbar and Start Menu, it's also in the control panel, is there an easy way to remove this but only from the start menu, preferably by editing the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reference to using resource hacker to accomplish what you are looking to do.  This goes a bit further then just a registry tweak, so YMMV.  It implies that you remove the appropriate menuitem.  I can't verify it on this system since it isn't XP, and frankly, I don't want to mess around with those files if I don't have to.

http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t452600.html

Comment: That removes the whole Settings sub menu so instead, in safe mode (using ResHacker with \windows\explorer.exe menu 204) I removed just the single line MENUITEM "&Taskbar and Start Menu", 413, MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED, compiled and saved it. This seems to have done it, and hopefully won't affect the system in any other way.